# Why can't I append to this list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to append my list but am getting a syntax error. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Can someone explain to me why it isn't proper?

[image]

Comment: Please put a [mcve], **in text form**, in the question itself.

Comment: Firsy: you should put the entire code and the stack trace as a part of your question text, not as an image. Second, your mistake is a typo in the last print. You forgot to close the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a right parenthesis in your last call to `print`.

Change it to:

```
print(len(stacy))
```

Comment: Questions like this should be closed as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error", not answered. (Leave a comment pointing out the typo if you like.)